# como puedo mostrar solamente el contenido de una notificacion

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() !=null){

    for (String Key:getIntent().getExtras().keySet()){

    String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Key);

    tvMostrarInfo.append("\n" + Key+":"+value);

    //...
}
```

Este es le código 
y si muestra el contenido pero con el id el from el nombre del paquete 
y solo quiero que se muestre el mensaje

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente revisa cual es el key del mensaje y lo agregas directamente, por ejemplo suponiendo que el key es "mensaje":

```
 if(Key.equals("mensaje")){
   String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Key);
   tvMostrarInfo.append("\n" + Key+":"+value);
 }
```

Comment: Gracias...Que tonta esa era la solución gracias me ayudó muchísimo